# RigidBody drag and drop with mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been trying to drag and drop a rigidbody. I have used this script. It's moving the rigidbody with mouse but does not drop the rigidbody, it keeps moving.

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour {

public Camera cam;
private float maxWidth;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    if (cam == null)
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }
    Vector3 upperCorner = new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0.0f);
    Vector3 targetWidth = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(upperCorner);
    float hatWidth = renderer.bounds.extents.x;
    maxWidth = targetWidth.x - hatWidth;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
    targetPosition = new Vector3(targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
    rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);


}
```

}

I want something like [this](http://www.unity3dsupport.com/uploads/110647/samples/bond/bond.html) example that means it will drag a gameobject having rigidbody and drop in place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) for begin drag,

[Input.GetMouseButton](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) for dragging,

[Input.GetMouseButtonUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) for end dragging.

Simple code is:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    // 0 means left mouse button.
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){ // Check left button is still down so change rigidbody position
       Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
       Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
       targetPosition = new Vector3(targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
       rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);
    }else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
       Vector3 startPositionRaw = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
       cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
```

Update for your need

```
 void FixedUpdate () {
        // 0 means left mouse button.
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){ // Check left button is still down so change rigidbody position
           RaycastHit hit;
           Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
           if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,100)){
               if(hit.collider.gameObject.name=="TargetObjectName"){
                  Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                   //This is your solution 
                   Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                   float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
                   targetPosition = new Vector3(targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);

                   // Maybe this is more usefull
                   Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                   rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);
               }
           }
        }else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
           Vector3 startPositionRaw = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
           Vector3 endPositionRaw = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
```

PS: Maybe, some syntax error in code i don't check it.

Comment: nice! Your code is serving my purpose, but I have some Unity UI (uGUI) buttons in the scene. When I press those buttons, the rigidbody jumps to the buttons. How can I stop this jumping?

Comment: It's totaly change according to your movement algorithm.If you don't want to go rigidbody to your button pos,you need to change your movement algorithm. Because in this example you sets Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f); so your mouse input gets the x position of button and set it's value to rigidbody.

Comment: If you want to go button position but not like teleporting.Want to move smooth you can use [Transform.Translate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) or  [Slerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) or [Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: Thanks for your hints.
I have already changed Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, rawPosition.y, 0.0f); since it will move on the both of x and y axis. 

The code is working like the rigidbody follows the mouse position but what I REALLY want is when the mouse just on the rigidbody position, the rigidbody will follow the mouse. So the algorithym will be like
if(mouse position is on the rigidbody) 
{ rigidbody will follow the mouse }

Could you help?

Comment: You need to use [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

Comment: Thanks I tried some codes using Raycast and RaycastHit yesterday before asking question here but could not make it. I will try again.